# Flask app is being run locally instead of on heroku

Tags: reactjs, flask, heroku

So I've deployed my flask app with react front end to heroku, but there seems to be some problem where flask is running on my local host instead of one the heroku server.

I've read tons of stackoverflow posts on this but to no resolution. Here is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__,static_folder="./build",static_url_path="/")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'my database url'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.secret_key = 'secret string'
CORS(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Feature_votes(db.Model):
    feature = db.Column(db.String(500), primary_key=True)
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, feature, votes, date):
        self.feature = feature
        self.votes = votes
        self.date = date

# Serve the react app
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")

# Retrieve currently polled features from Feature_votes
@app.route("/getVotes", methods=['GET'])
def getVotes():
    rows = Feature_votes.query.filter().order_by(Feature_votes.date)
    response = []
    for row in rows:
        response.append(
            {"feature": row.feature,
             "votes": row.votes
        })
    
    return flask.jsonify(response)

# Add a new feature to the db with votes set to 0
@app.route("/featureAdd", methods=['POST'])
def featureAdd():
    feature = request.get_json()["feature"]
    featureEntry = Feature_votes(feature, 0, datetime.utcnow())
    db.session.add(featureEntry)
    db.session.commit()

    response = {"feature": featureEntry.feature,
                "votes": 0,
                "date": featureEntry.date
                }

    return response
  

@app.route("/featureModifyVotes", methods=['POST'])
def featureUnvote():
    feature = request.get_json()["feature"]
    direction = request.get_json()["direction"]
    featureEntry = Feature_votes.query.filter_by(feature=feature).first()
    
    if (direction == "increase"):
        featureEntry.votes += 1
    else:
        featureEntry.votes -= 1
    
    db.session.commit()
    response = {featureEntry.feature: featureEntry.votes}
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT server:app
```

Also here is a snip I took from inspect element to show that this request is being served locally.
[image]

I am relatively new to web development so it is possible I made a lot of mistakes. Please let me know if you can help or need any more info from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently that screenshot I posted in the question didn't mean that my server was running on localhost, but rather that my request was being made to the localhost. Turns out I had fetch("http://localhost...) in my build files. After using a relative path, rebuilding and pushing to heroku, everything is working.